# Get EditText value with event handler in MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I have a dialog in MapBasic that includes an EditText control, a PopupMenu control and a button. When the user presses the button a sub is called. In this sub I would like to get the values of the EditText and PopupMenu, do some maths with them and then output the results into a second EditText control (which will be disabled so as to be used for output only).

My question is how do I get the values from the EditText and Popupmenu controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function I was looking for was ReadControlValue().